# Context of Big O notation in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics

While reading a paper, I came across a statement saying

"The vertical vorticity components are assumed O(1), while the horizontal vorticity components are assumed to be weaker."

I don't fully grasp what they're saying. I've looked up Big-O notation on the web, but the conversation is often centered around computational complexity with algorithms. I've also found some formal mathematical statements, but again, I don't understand the context in the statement above.

Can anyone offer any insights what people mean when they say O(1) when discussing dimensionless PDEs governing some physical processes (fluids in this case)?

Comment: What’s the paper? Link?

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation, while it is very popular in computer science, is about the growth of functions. In computer science, the functions they are worried about happen to be measuring system resources like number of operations required (and hence the time it takes to run) and space in memory. The basic idea, though, is just functions.

The context in which this notation usually appears in physics is Taylor series, specifically when trying to do an approximation/perturbative calculation. Suppose I had some function $f(x)$ which had a Taylor expansion
$$
f(x)=f_0+f_1x+f_2x^2+\cdots.
$$
In most physics applications, you don't want to keep all orders...part of the point of a Taylor expansion is that you can drop higher order terms if $x$ is small enough. If we are only doing a calculation out to, say, first order in $x$, we might write
$$
f(x)=f_0+f_1x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)
$$
so in some sense we are able to think about the big-O here as telling us "everything we are dropping by putting this $\mathcal{O}$ here is of order $x^2$ or higher."

For a perhaps familiar example, take the equation of motion for a pendulum which looks, roughly, like
$$
\ddot \theta=-\sin \theta,
$$
ignoring constants that don't matter for us. It's fairly common to use the small angle approximation $\sin \theta\approx \theta$ for sufficiently small $\theta$. But really this approximation is just taking the Taylor series for the sine and arguing that higher order terms in the expansion can be neglected if $\theta$ is small. Using big-O, we could write this as
$$
\ddot\theta=-\theta+\mathcal{O}(\theta^3)
$$
since the next neglected term is of order $\theta^3$ (the sine has no second order term in its Taylor expansion).

This notation can also be helpful when doing calculations to keep track of the orders of the expressions. For example, if we were to multiply two functions which have only been kept to first order, then also keeping the result to first order we would have
$$
(A_0+A_1 x+\mathcal{O}(x^2))(B_0+B_1x+\mathcal{O}(x^2))=A_0B_0+A_1B_0x+A_0B_1x+\mathcal{O}(x^2),
$$
noting that we have absorbed also the term resulting from multiplying the two linear terms into the order $x^2$ and higher stuff right away. No need to keep it if we are only working to first order anyway.

So, when the paper says something is order $\mathcal{O}(1)$, they mean it's zeroth order (zero powers) in whatever parameter they are expanding in. A word of caution though: this sort of thinking is so common in physics, many physicists are often not very explicit about introducing an explicit parameter to expand everything in. Instead, it's left to be "understood" by the reader that, if we bothered to introduce such a parameter to expand in, then we could talk about the orders just the same. So the specific statement you quote from that paper almost certainly means (but of course, I don't know the paper so I haven't read it) "suppose we are expanding in some parameter $\kappa$ such that if we were to expand the vertical components in $\kappa$ the first term in the expansion would be zeroth order in $\kappa$, while we assume the horizontal component to have no zeroth order term, so the first non-zero term in the horizontal component's expansion will have some power in $\kappa$ greater than or equal to 1. If we are taking $\kappa$ to be small, it follows that the vertical components will be larger than the horizontal ones." Obviously that's a lot more to say, but that's essentially the idea.

I'll also mention that the analog of $\kappa$ that they are using might be explicitly mentioned somewhere. In fluid mechanics specifically, there's a wide variety of parameters that people expand in depending upon the situation. For example Reynolds number is a common one. Everything I have described here is also expansions about a small parameter. There are also expansions about large parameters that people do. By and large this is equivalent to saying "if I'm expanding about $\kappa$ *large*, then that's equivalent to expanding about $1/\kappa$ small" so you can go back and forth between the two. This will, however, result in you seeing things like $\mathcal{O}(1/\kappa)$.